# Reading values from Excel into a vector in Python results in empty elements

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, vector, cell

After reading a list of values from an Excel spreadsheet using Python, the vector contains empty elements, followed by the raw values. The list of values are in column #6 and are between rows #8 through #13.

```
rows = 12
i = 7
vector_a = []
for i in range(rows): 
    raw_value = sheet.cell_value(i, 5)
    vector_a.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 5))
```

vector_a contains the following elements:

```
['',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'total',
 '',
 9.679525,
 40.436545,
 42.815155,
 39.743423,
 24.01737]
```

While I could use the vector_a.pop(0) command seven times to get rid of the first seven elements, I want the vector to start from the first raw value (9.679525).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely undestand the desired output (if it's only in column 6 and row 8-13), but assuming that vector_a are a float target data you could do some for iteration and get these values like:

```
for elem in vector_a:
    if isinstance(elem, float):
        print(elem)
```

or with list comprehension

```
numbers = [elem for elem in vector_a if isinstance(elem, float)]
```

Both of the code above will only get the last 5 elements of your vector_a

But if you really work with csv files, take a look on [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/#), it's a very good library for spreadsheets.

Comment: Thank you for your time in looking into this, I appreciate it a lot. I will check it out and provide an update.